# Create Glue data catalog via Athena SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-sdk-js, aws-glue-data-catalog

I would like to use Athena to run queries on data in an S3 bucket in another AWS account. I am using Javascript SDK. Reading through the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Athena.html), I understand that I must first create a data catalog that will point Athena to the correct S3 location.

I think that I have to call the [createDataCatalog](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Athena.html#createDataCatalog-property) method. Most of the arguments for this method are self-explanatory, except for the "parameters" argument, which seems to contain information about how the data catalog will be created. But I am unable to find anywhere how these parameters should look.

So my questions are:

1. What are the parameters to provide to here?
2. Is this the right way to create a glue data catalog (including database and table)?
3. Once done, will this allow me to run Athena queries on the data catalog?

Comment: Athena DC is old, now Athena is using Glue DC which you already have. You can create crawler in your account to crawl data in S3 in other account. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't know what a crawler is. Basically, I want to use Athena to run SQL queries on data in S3 in another account. I want to do it programatically via JS SDK, not manually via console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple use case with static S3 data,

- We first need to create Glue Table using Glue [createTable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Glue.html#createTable-property) API pointing to S3 location. Few Examples in cli [documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/glue/create-table.html).
- Run queries against this Glue Table from [Athena](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javascript/example_code/athena/index.js)

Here is an example to create Glue Database and Table

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });

const glue = new AWS.Glue();
const dbName = "test-db";
glue.createDatabase(
  {
    DatabaseInput: {
      Name: dbName,
    },
  },
  function (dbCrtErr, dbRsp) {
    if (dbCrtErr.message === "Database already exists." || dbRsp) {
      console.log("dbRsp", dbRsp);
      glue.createTable(
        {
          DatabaseName: dbName,
          TableInput: {
            Name: "my-table",
            Parameters: {
              classification: "json",
              compressionType: "none",
            },
            TableType: "EXTERNAL_TABLE",
            StorageDescriptor: {
              Location: "s3://my-s3-bucket-with-events/",
              InputFormat:
                "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat",
              OutputFormat:
                "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat",
              Columns: [
                {
                  Name: "id",
                  Type: "string",
                },
                {
                  Name: "name",
                  Type: "string",
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        function (error, response) {
          console.log("error", error, "response", response);
        }
      );
    } else {
      console.log("dbCrtErr", dbCrtErr);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: This is helpful, but I'm reaching the same problem. What should be the parameters to create Glue database and a Glue table afterwards?

Comment: I updated answer with an link to create table examples, Parameters will look something like`{ 'classification': 'json', 'compressionType': 'none' }`

Comment: I added an example to create glue database and table.

Comment: How do you specify in which AWS account these resources get created?

Comment: it will use just AWS credential chain unless we initialize sdk specifically with some auth keys. so, these will be created in account behind those credentials.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find what to input as "InputFormat", into "parameters", etc.? I am reading through documentation, but there is nothing about what should go into parameters, only that it's "A map array of key-value pairs.". The same for input/output format. "The input format: SequenceFileInputFormat (binary), or TextInputFormat, or a custom format." Where did you find the full name for parquet as you have it here?

Comment: Could you update your question for SDK3?